# Role of foreground points in pcl::MinCutSegmentation

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, max-flow

I am trying to understand how does MinCutSegmentation work in PCL. I am setting some points as foreground points, but regardless of what points I chose as my foreground points, I get the same result. The segmentation basically crops some part of my point cloud and returns the remaining part as "foreground".

My understanding from reading the paper for MinCut was that the points I select as foreground should definitely be marked as foreground in the final cluster, however, I am seeing that that doesn't happen. Following are some screenshots to explain what's happening:

[image: Original point cloud]

Original point cloud

[image: I am setting the points inside the red box as foreground points]

I am setting the points inside the red box as foreground points

[image: The segmented cloud has these point marked as foreground and no points marked as background. Note that regardless of what points I chose as foreground, i still get the same output]
The segmented cloud has these point marked as foreground and no points marked as background. Note that regardless of what points I chose as foreground, i still get the same output

In addition and possibly related to the first question, I am not understanding how am I losing some points during the mincut algorithm. My understanding was that the entire point cloud gets divided into two parts - foreground and background, but that doesn't seem to be the case when I am trying out the algorithm. Any pointers?

Following is a code snippet that I am using:

```
  //xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax represent the extremeties of the red box

  float xmin = startX - delta; 
  float xmax = startX + delta; 
  float ymin = startY - delta; 
  float ymax = startY + delta; 
  float zmin = startZ - delta; 
  float zmax = startZ + delta; 

  pcl::CropBox<pcl::PointXYZRGB> boxFilter;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr filteredCloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>) ;
  boxFilter.setMin(Eigen::Vector4f(xmin, ymin, zmin, 0.0));
  boxFilter.setMax(Eigen::Vector4f(xmax, ymax, zmax, 0.0));
  boxFilter.setInputCloud(cloud_target);
  boxFilter.filter(*filteredCloud);
   // For this code, mode is always "mincut". 
  // I am using the crop mode to just test what points are selected by the boxfilter
  if(mode == "crop")
  {

    viewer->removePointCloud("sample cloud");
          viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(filteredCloud, "sample cloud");
          viewer->spinOnce(1);
  }
  else if(mode == "mincut")
  {
     pcl::IndicesPtr indices (new std::vector <int>);
     pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
     pass.setInputCloud (cloud_target);
     pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
     pass.setFilterLimits (0.0, 1.0);
     pass.filter (*indices);

     pcl::MinCutSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZRGB> seg;
     seg.setInputCloud (cloud_target);
     seg.setIndices (indices);
     seg.setForegroundPoints (filteredCloud);

      seg.setSigma (0.15);
      seg.setRadius (10);
      seg.setNumberOfNeighbours (14);
      seg.setSourceWeight (0.3);

      std::vector <pcl::PointIndices> clusters;

      std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      seg.extract (clusters); 
      std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

      std::cout << "Time taken to segment = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() <<std::endl;



      std::cout << "Maximum flow is " << seg.getMaxFlow () << std::endl;

      pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr colored_cloud = seg.getColoredCloud ();


      viewer->removePointCloud("sample cloud");
      viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(colored_cloud, "sample cloud");
      viewer->spinOnce(1);
```

Comment: can you share the code you are using?

Comment: Some preliminary questions: What exactly is your objective? Segmenting that staircase? Is the mincut segmentation [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/min_cut_segmentation.php) code, using the tutorial [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PointCloudLibrary/data/master/tutorials/min_cut_segmentation_tutorial.pcd) working for you?

FYI: your post to the pcl users mailing didn't get delivered to my mailbox.

Comment: My objective is to allow a user to segment a part of the pointcloud based on their initial selection. So, for example, in this case, I was hoping to select everything but the books. The tutorial data file works as expected, but I couldn't get any other point cloud file to work. Shouldn't the points I selected as foreground, definitely be a part of foreground cluster min cut returns?

Comment: I believe so. In the tutorial, they provide a single point as the foreground indicator, in this case you're using the result of a filtering step. Did you confirm that `filteredCloud` actually has points? If the original data works but yours doesn't then it might be an indication that your parameters are unsuitable for the data you have. A good way to test it is setting the radius and the sigma really high (more than the min max range of your entire cloud)and see if everything get's selected as foreground.

Comment: I confirmed that filteredCloud actually has points. I was playing around with the code more and with the same code I get results that I would expect when I use the point cloud provided in the tutorial. For any other point cloud, it just doesn't work for me. I understand that the parameters might be unsuitable (and i conducted experiments as you suggested as well), but i thought by explicitly marking some points as foreground, I should have gotten those points as foregrounds in the final result, regardless of the parameters. Is that not the expected behaviour?